# How to make an add friend/defriend function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a site where people can create a profile. But I am trying to figure out how to start on making an add friend button so users can have friends.

In my user table, i have user_id, first_name, last_name, email, etc.

Should I somehow relate the user_id of the user and the friend in a friend table?

I am a novice to programming, so these things are still new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let's try to keep this simple.
You're trying, essentially, to find a way to connect two users together.

Since I'm trying to keep things simple, and definitely not implying that this is the best way of doing it, I think the **easiest** way to go about doing this is to create a new table (users_friends) with the following fields: (user_id) and (friend_id).

Well, so let's say my user_id is 5.
Your user_id is 10.

I want to add you as my friend, therefore I'd add an entry to that newly created table with the following values:
user_id = 5, friend_id = 10.

So, let's say you want to display all of my friends, you could run a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` IN ( SELECT `friend_id` FROM `users_friends` WHERE `user_id` = '5' );
```

Sure enough, removing a friend is easy, all you have to do is delete the entry from the newly created table ...

```
DELETE FROM `users_friends` WHERE `user_id` = '5' AND `friend_id` = '10';
```

And poof, you're suddenly not my friend anymore ;)

So yeah, these are the basics.
I'd try this solution before moving on to a solution which will allow you more flexibility.

Comment: to be clear - this scheme more like twitter model with followers/followings, not facebook one with "real" friends. i mean at facebook we get 2-side relation when each user have to add a friend (i don't know the implementation but i bet it's 2 records adding into friends table) before real relation is created.

Comment: you should be able to reverse the query like: SELECT `user_id` FROM `users_friends` WHERE `friend_id` = '5'

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
create table users(
 user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 username varbinary(32) not null
)engine=innodb;


create table user_friends(
 user_id int unsigned not null,
 friend_user_id int unsigned not null,
 primary key (user_id, friend_user_id)
)engine=innodb;
```

to display a user's set of friends:

```
select
 u.*
from
 user_friends uf
inner join users u on uf.friend_user_id = u.user_id
where
 uf.user_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement f00 and Isaac answer:

1. basic pseudo-code would be like this:
2. have button / URL in your profile page (maybe http://example.com/makefriend.php?memberid=$memberid). Let's call it 'make friend'
3. makefriend.php will then check memberid from that particular profile page.
4. makefriend.php will too get requesterid from requester (this is usually saved on session).

   - if empty, maybe not logged in.
5. Next, makefriend.php will insert memberid and requesterid to, says, friendlist.

Comment: 2 should be sent via POST with csrf-token otherwise it's pretty simple to friendify anyone using CSRF-attack

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a friends table that holds a value for user1 and user2. Whenever a friend request is sent, user2 is the requester while user1 is the requested. This makes it much more easier to know the follower and who was actually followed.....  user2 is the follower while user1 is the followed. So if your username falls under user1 that means you are being followed by user2 and if your username falls under user2 that means you are following user1.....  This makes it much easier for you. You can get your friends by selecting from friends table where user1 = your userid or user2 = your userid. If user1 =your userid then user2 is your friend elseif user2 = your userid, then user1 is your friend. You can store this in an array. Then for each array, you can find their user details. Hope you understand? 
You can add delete friends by simply deleting the column where user1=your userid and user2=your friendid or user1=your friendid and user2=your userid..... Pretty simple.

If you are requesting
Request friends by:
Insert into friends(id,user1,user2,accepted) values(' ', $yourfriendid,$youruserid,'0');

If you are being requested by someone, 
Request will be by:
Insert into friends(id,user1,user2,accepted) values(' ',$youruserid,$yourfriendid,'0');

Once the request is accepted, the accepted column becomes ONE (1) instead of zero(0). All you need to do is to update the Column by setting accepted=1 once the friend has been accepted by user1.

To unfriend:
Simply delete the row that contains both your userid and yourfriendid as either of user1 or user2.

Blocking a friend:
You may need another table where you can add your list of blocked users.... But if you are familiar with json_encode and json_decode function, it will be easier to store your blocked users into one array all you need is to save that array using json_encode into your database. You can fetch the array from database, convert it to real array using json_decode, then you can remove any blocked user or add a newly blocked user into that array before saving back into your database....  This will likely conserve space. So all your blocked users will just be in one row that contains your userid.