# Select user details from a self relationship table

Tags: sql, relationship

I have 3 tables (user, relationship and user_type) with these data (the relevant ones):

```
USER TABLE:
id, username, avatar, user_type_id

RELATIONSHIP TABLE:
id, user_id1, user_id2, relationship_points

USER_TYPE
id
```

I'm trying to create a single entry per relationship so, user with id "1" could be in user_id1 OR user_id2 in a relationship, so, I don't have to duplicate unnecessary data.

I already created (thanks to another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542800/how-to-make-an-add-friend-defriend-function-in-php/2542842#2542842)) a query to select all relationship details from an user, but only if it's id is in "user_id1".

```
    SELECT
        r.id AS relationship_id,
        r.relationship_points AS points,
        u.username AS username,
        u.avatar_url AS avatar
    FROM
        relationship AS r
    INNER JOIN
        user AS u
    ON
        r.user_id2 = u.id
    INNER JOIN
        user_type AS t
    ON
        u.user_type_id = t.id
    WHERE
        r.user_id1 = ?
```

But, as you can see, if the user is in "user_id2", it doesn't work.

I know I could make another query, but I think it's the "easy, lazy" way, and I would love to learn how to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this makes the trick:

```
SELECT
    r.id AS relationship_id,
    r.relationship_points AS points,
    u.username AS username,
    u.avatar_url AS avatar
FROM relationship AS r
INNER JOIN user u
ON r.user_id2 = u.id OR r.user_id1 = u.id
INNER JOIN user_type AS t
ON u.user_type_id = t.id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Comment: Almost… (I just saw this answer NOW… sorry).

Comment: The result from the query fails with the user data… all data comes from the "main" user instead of his friends…